# what is the best way to get the "It’s Always 5 O’Clock Somewhere" hat

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015

I have been trying to get the "It’s Always 5 O’Clock Somewhere" and I am not sure what is the best way to get it?

I was reading that you need to post at question when its 5pm?

[image]

Comment: [Winter Bash 2015 Secret Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats)